# Infinite sum of infinite products

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinite-product

Is there a solution for the infinite sum of the following form??

$x^y + x^{y + y^2} + x^{y + y^2 + y^3} + x^{y + y^2 + y^3 + y^4} + ...$

It can also be represented this way:

$\sum_{j = 1}^{\infty} \prod_{k = 1}^{j} x^{y^k}$

Any tips would be greatly appreciated-- both me and Wolfram Alpha are stumped on this one!

Comment: Another possible representation: $x^{\frac{y}{1 - y}} \left [ \sum_{j = 2}^{\infty} x^{\frac{-y^j}{1 - y}} \right ]$

Comment: Wait, actually I think the sum is infinite. So, answer away for easy points!

Comment: It depends - if $x=1/2$ and $y\gt 1$, it certainly converges.